# Is there a way to use javascript variable as part of PHP SQL page?

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I have a variable within a laravel PHP page, held within Javascript. I currently print / output this as:

```
${data.id}
```

I now want to connect to PHPMyAdmin to check to see if the ID is within a table. However, I realise I can't use the ID number in PHP - as this is done on the server side and JS on the client side. A little stuck.

Unfortunately, I'm on a shared hosting package so node.js isn't a solution I can use.

Any help would be great! I think I can use AJAX, but unsure on how this would look.

Comment: Use Ajax in jQuery to send an asynchronius call to PHP

Comment: Thank you . What would that look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here the AJAX sample.

```js
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { id: data.id}
})
  .done(function( response) {
    console.log(response);
    //TODO:process your response here if receive response from php file.

  });
```

Comment: Thank you. OK. Within 'some.php', how does the variable get passed?

$select = 'SELECT *';
$from = ' FROM table ';
$where = ' WHERE id = $id ORDER BY $id DESC LIMIT 5';

Comment: In PHP you can get this value from $_POST and then use it however you like.